# Data has same value for every dimension after PCA

Tags: pca

I encountered a bug(?) after performing PCA on a big dataset. I have ca. 2000 measurements and ca. 50 features / dimensions. I perform PCA to reduce the number of dimensions. I want to have only 20-30 dimensions. But my data does look strange after I project it into new PCA feature space. Every dimension has the same values, except for the first. It doesnt matter how many dimensions I set for PCA, my data does always look like this: (three dimensions as example and four measurements)

```
10075.1;2.00177e-23;7.70922e-43
10114.6;2.00177e-23;7.70922e-43
10192.9;2.00177e-23;7.70922e-43
9843.2;2.00177e-23;7.70922e-43
```

What is the reason? Why do I have good data only for the first feature?
This is the original data:

```
0;24;54;167;19.3625;46;24;21;298.575;254.743;1.17207;1.73611;2.26757;18;15;14;12;9;8;4;15;13;12;9;8;4;33;28;26;21;17;15;8;0;0;1;92283.9;19441.8;16337;11731.8;6796.85;2215.39;1861.07;3516.91;4587.27;4130.99;7.38638;8;9.41167;10.5923;14;19.9733
0;24;54;167;19.3625;45;23;21;272.609;244.143;1.11659;1.89036;2.26757;17;15;14;11;9;7;4;16;13;12;9;8;4;33;28;26;20;17;14;8;0;1;1;92298.5;19414.8;16445.3;11871.4;6873.36;2071.48;1845.56;4483;4588.43;2854.95;7.06929;8;9.08176;10.0947;14;19.1412
0;24;54;167;19.3625;45;23;21;256.58;248.081;1.03426;1.89036;2.26757;17;15;14;11;9;7;4;15;13;12;9;8;4;32;28;26;20;17;14;8;0;1;1;92262.9;19449.6;16602.1;12066.9;6875.38;1762.22;1813.8;4461.31;4605.87;4540.53;6.72761;7;9.17784;10.0404;14;19.0638
0;24;54;167;19.3625;45;22;23;228.664;293.1;0.780157;2.06612;1.89036;16;14;13;10;8;7;4;17;14;13;10;8;3;33;28;26;20;16;13;7;1;0;0;92047.3;19594.2;16615.9;11855.3;6357.26;1412.1;1931.18;3292.93;4305.41;3125.78;7.14206;7;9.15515;10.0013;14;18.9998
```

Here are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

```
120544647.296627;
1055287.207309433;
788517.1814841435

4.445188101138883e-06, -1.582751359550716e-06, 0.0001194540407426801, 8.805619419232736e-05, 1.718812629108742e-05, -6.478627494871924e-06, 1.866065159173557e-06, -8.102268773738454e-06, 0.001575116366026065, 0.001368858662087531, 2.42338448583798e-06, 1.468791084230193e-07, 1.619495879919206e-08, 2.045676050284675e-06, 4.522426974955079e-06, 1.935642018365442e-06, 9.400348593348646e-07, 3.50785209102226e-06, -6.886458171608557e-07, -2.272864941126205e-06, -4.576437628645375e-06, -3.711985547436847e-06, -4.179746481364989e-06, -1.080958836802159e-06, 3.018347636693104e-06, -5.401065369031065e-08, -1.776343529071431e-06, -3.239711622030108e-06, 2.426893254220096e-06, 2.329701819532251e-06, -1.335049163771412e-06, -2.016447535744125e-06, -2.48848684914049e-06, 1.034821043317487e-06, 0.9509463574053698, 0.2040750414336948, 0.1698045366243798, 0.1221511665292666, 0.06648621927929886, 0.01787357780337607, 0.02181878649610538, 0.04094056949392437, 0.04589005034245261, 0.03602144595540402, 4.638015609510389e-05, -9.594011737623517e-07, 5.643329708389021e-05, 6.49999142971481e-05, 6.708699420903862e-07, 0.0001209291154324417;
 -1.193874321738139e-05, -3.042062337012123e-05, -0.0001368023572559274, -0.0001093928140002418, -1.847065231448535e-05, 3.847106756849437e-05, -1.23803319528626e-05, 2.082402112096706e-06, -0.002107941678699949, -0.0007526438176676972, -1.304240623192574e-06, -4.358106348750469e-06, 4.189661461745327e-06, 3.972537960568455e-07, 5.415441896012467e-06, -3.487031299718403e-06, -3.082927770719131e-06, -6.180776247962886e-06, -3.293811231853141e-06, -3.069190535161948e-06, 9.242946297782889e-06, 1.849824602072292e-06, 8.007250998398399e-06, 9.597348504390614e-06, -7.976030386807306e-07, 1.465838819379542e-05, -1.637206697646072e-06, 4.924323227679534e-06, 3.416572256427778e-06, -4.091414270533951e-06, 3.950956777004832e-06, -1.425709512894606e-05, -1.612907157276045e-06, -1.656147283798045e-06, 0.01791626179130883, -0.03865588909604983, -0.02237813174629856, -0.011581970882016, 0.008401303497694863, 0.00598682750741207, -0.02647921936520565, -0.08745349044258101, -0.6199482703379527, 0.7776587660292456, -2.204501859699998e-05, 3.065799954216684e-06, -0.0001088757748474737, -9.070630703475932e-05, -1.507680849966721e-05, -0.000203298163659711;
 2.141350692234778e-05, 3.763794188497906e-05, 0.0002682046623337108, 0.0002761646438217766, 2.250001958053043e-05, -4.493680340744517e-05, 1.71038513853044e-05, 4.793887034272248e-05, -0.002472775598056956, -0.002583273192861402, -2.360815196252781e-05, 8.57575614248591e-07, -2.277442903271404e-06, -9.431493206768549e-06, 2.836934896747011e-06, 1.836715455464421e-05, 2.384241283455247e-05, 4.963711569589484e-06, 1.390892651258379e-05, 2.354454084909798e-05, 2.358174073858803e-05, 3.953694936818999e-05, 3.859322887829735e-05, 4.383431246805508e-06, 9.501429817743515e-06, 2.641867563533516e-05, 5.790410392283418e-05, 6.243564171284964e-05, 9.347142816394926e-06, 2.341035633032736e-05, 3.140572721234472e-05, 2.567884918875704e-06, -2.488581283389154e-06, -1.083945623896245e-05, -0.02381539022135584, 0.1464545802416884, 0.09922198413600333, 0.009864006965697942, -0.07588888859083308, -0.1732512868035658, 0.2074803672415529, 0.5543971362454099, -0.6344797023718978, -0.4234201679790431, -0.0001368109107852992, 2.172633922404158e-07, -0.0001132510107743674, -7.90184051908068e-05, 1.89704719379068e-05, -0.0001862727476251848
```

I thought the reason why there is so much variance for the first feature was because the first eigenvalues is very big in comparison with the other two. When I normalize my data before PCA, I get very similar eigenvalues:

```
0.6660936495675316;
0.6449413383086006;
0.383110906838073
```

But the data still looks similar after projecting it in PCA space:

```
-0.816894;7.1333e-67;2.00113e-23
-0.822324;7.1333e-67;2.00113e-23
-0.831973;7.1333e-67;2.00113e-23
-0.822553;7.1333e-67;2.00113e-23
```

Comment: Is this a C++ question?  Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all your data for features 2, 3, and 4 are very close or exactly the same as the first feature, which is why your results are not very great. The magnitude of the differences may also not be significant enough to capture the variance of the data.

PCA works by getting the covariances between the features. You might want to check out the covariance matrix produced by PCA. I suspect that all the values are very close to each other. Most of the variance is captured by the first eigenvector of the matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I only posted a part of my data, but I have other values for feature 1-4, too. One time I tried normalzing my data because I hoped to get better variance but this didnt help either. I will post the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but calculating the covairiance matrix will take me some time.

Comment: If you're using a library like sklearn you should be able to get the covariance matrix pretty easily. But yeah, the eigenvalues indicate that the first eigenvector dominates the other ones. You can take the first (largest) eigenvalue and divide by the sum of the eigenvalues and that's relatively how much of the variance is captured by the first eigenvector.